# Codeigniter make directory if not exist

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, mkdir

Hi can anyone help me with this. Basically I used the file uploading class of codeigniter the link is 
[here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)
and it works fine! but I need to know how to create directory inside this default upload path `$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'` the name of the folder is the date today this is my sample code.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'.$date;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';


if (!is_dir('uploads/'.$date)) {
mkdir('./uploads/' . $date, 0777, TRUE);

}
```

and I got an error like

```
Message: mkdir(): Invalid argument
```

I search how it will be fix and they say this `0777` CI permission will do, but still it won't work for me.

Thanks for any response.

Comment: **":"** colon character is not allowed in directory name.

Comment: try to give complete path. and enclosed in in double quotes.

Comment: @elavarasanlee thanks for that info I'll try it now, and will get back to you if it fix

Comment: Use `date('Y-m-d H.i.s')` instead of ':'.

Comment: I have tried $date = 'abc' line two of above code, to test if date thing is my problem here, but still i got the same error

Comment: wait exclude ":" works, sorry for that. thanks guys!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The date format wil have specail chars like `-` and `:`

I'm not sure about the `-` but `:` is not allowed on an map. So you have to delete that char out `$date`.

```
$date = str_replace( ':', '', $date);
if (!is_dir('uploads/'.$date)) {
    mkdir('./uploads/' . $date, 0777, TRUE);

}
```

or use as [elavarasan lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1621781/elavarasan-lee) said use:

```
date('Y-m-d H.i.s')
```

Comment: @kodewrecker, no problem. Glad i could help. Don't forget that you must change the date BEFORE you set it up in the codeigniter config. Or else that wil fail still ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
if(!is_dir($config['upload_path'])) mkdir($config['upload_path'], 0777, TRUE);
```

Comment: This answer is in the Low Quality Posts review queue because it's just a line of code with no explanation. Please explain what your code does and how it answers the question.

Comment: Good answer doesn't need explanation. This is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are new to codeigniter and previously in php you used code for making directory like

```
$target_dir="../../media/profile/".date('my')."/";
    if(!file_exists($target_dir)){
        mkdir($target_dir,0777);
    }
```

then in codeignitor you can use only one dot for outside directory path

```
$target_dir="././media/profile/".date('my')."/";
    if(!file_exists($target_dir)){
        mkdir($target_dir,0777);
    }
```

this one solved my problem.