# How to create a folder in codeigniter

Tags: php, directory

I am creating a folder with mkdir() in php but I don't know how to create a folder in CodeIgniter. Anyone can tell me how to create that with mkdir() function.

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18217147/10430605

Comment: @NikhileshAgrawal Actually that's a PHP code...I need to Codeigniter customized code

Comment: CodeIgniter _is_ PHP. It's just a framework.

Comment: follow the given link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58428797/7327310
perhaps, it will help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Codeigniter make directory if not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435597/codeigniter-make-directory-if-not-exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a folder using `mkdir()` like this `mkdir($path,0777,true)`.
For example if your codeigniter project structure is like `C:\xampp\htdocs\Prjects Folder\...` and you want to create a folder inside **assets folder** (i.e for images you want to create an **Image folder**) then you can create it like this.

```
if(!is_dir('././assets/images') )
        {
            mkdir('././assets/images',0777,TRUE);
        }
```

**Note:** To know more about **mkdir()** check this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Answer (score 1):

First add your path using `realpath` function which gives you absolute path and then use `mkdir` to create folder.

Example: 
Here i am store one image within folder because it is not exist so i have to create folder first then i have to add.

```
$path = realpath(APPPATH . 'images/test.jpg');

if(!file_exists($path))
{
   mkdir($path,0777,TRUE);
}
```

**Note**: PHP or Codeigniter, we can follow same process to create directory.